# Failing Assertion does not fail/terminate the current test case in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js, assertion

I am using nightwatch.js and have written a test case, and using `browser.assert.equals()`. But even if the assertion fails, it does not terminate the test case. It just throws an assertion error and declares the test case as passed. How do we terminate the current test case and declare it as fail?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that you've written?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem, and the solution was, to add a return statement to the step definition. That is, because I use nightwatch-cucumber, and, as the docu says, here its necessary:

"Step definition handling

Step definitons which uses Nightwatch client should return the result of api call as it returns a Promise. Please note that this behaviour is different from plain Nightwatch client API."
http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/